# Why do I get a line break after a <span> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, nowrap

Why do I get a line-break? I use the following: White-space: nowrap; but when I fill in the span a line-break appears. What is causing this?

```
function insertLinkHoverImage(datei,datei2,verlinkung) 
        {
            var doc = document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document;

            var range = doc.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var nnode = doc.createElement("span");
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            var image = doc.createElement("img");
            image.src = "http://www.galliano.cc/Test_seite/cms/uploads/"+datei;         
            //Wenn Bild hochgeladen wurde
            image.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("imgwidth").value = image.width;
                document.getElementById("imgheight").value = image.height;


                var alink = doc.createElement("a");
                var classDatei2 = "";

                alink.href = verlinkung;
                classDatei2 = datei.replace(".","-");

                nnode.setAttribute("style","white-space: nowrap; background-image:url(http://www.galliano.cc/Test_seite/cms/uploads/"+datei+"); width:"+document.getElementById("imgwidth").value+"px; height: "+document.getElementById("imgheight").value+"px; display: block; background-repeat: no-repeat;");               

                alink.appendChild(nnode);
                range.insertNode(alink);
            }

        }
```

Comment: when i insert the span i get a <br> after the insert. so the Image is not in the same line like the the  other words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your JavaScript, you have:

```
var nnode = doc.createElement("span");
```

and then you have:

```
nnode.setAttribute("style","white-space: nowrap; 
background-image:url(...);     
width:"+document.getElementById("imgwidth").value+"px; 
height: "+document.getElementById("imgheight").value+"px; 
display: block; background-repeat: no-repeat;");
```

So the `span` is by default, an inline element, but then you specify `display: block` in your inline style, which makes it a block level element, and that will give you your line break.

Try using `display: inline-block`.